# Global, CSS independent bar that developers can include on their sites

Tags: css, include, navigation, code-reuse

I am developing a "bar" like what you see on the top of many default Blogger blogs that acts as a unifying element on otherwise different-looking sites. I want to package the code up into a neat package so that I can give other developers a few simple lines of code that they can paste into the beginning of their `<body>`.

I know there are many ways to do this, like using PHP includes, AJAX calls, JavaScript and XmlHttpRequest, Google closure templates, etc. BUT I want to make sure the bar is CSS independent, meaning other CSS that is used on the site does not affect my bar.

I am wondering what is the best method to accomplish this? Is inline CSS the only way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Just like JavaScript plugin development, there's no guarantee that CSS classes and IDs wont be overridden later.

If the code *needs* to be inline, I'd suggest namespacing all of your classes and IDs: `pluginname-wrapper`, `pluginname-container`, `pluginname-block`, etc.

Otherwise, you could use an `iframe` element to store a miniature page.

I'd suggest sticking to namespacing. If someone includes your plugin and it's off by a bit, they'll be able to manually override the styles to make it look the way they want.

Someone who writes `div {float:left;}` or anything similarly silly will have problems either way, so don't worry about making it the same for everyone, just make it work with the default styles.